# Why does Google think I’m in Korea from every device on my home network when I am in Canada?

Tags: networking, geolocation, localization

I’m not sure when this started happening but every device (e.g. laptop, phones, tablets, etc…) at home, Google thinks I’m in Korea when I’m actually in Canada. I tried using [Geo IP Tool](http://www.geoiptool.com) to double-check and it shows I’m in Canada as well.

Where do I begin troubleshooting this? I tried going through my router and there’s nothing I could find relating to locale.

Comment: I did a few months ago but have not used TOR for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a Google problem and not yours, so there is no simple fix. Google is detecting your IP incorrectly. Google has a page to report this and they say it might take up to a month for them to do so.

Here's the Google main article:
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/873?hl=en

Here's the report page:
https://support.google.com/websearch/contact/ip

Comment: Interesting...I wonder where they are getting the location from that makes it so off.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's just happening on one computer, you can change your search settings location:

https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&fg=1#location

Comment: No, it's happening on every computer/laptop, phone, etc.

Comment: Oops.  I should have caught that in the original question.  Is there any sort of nonstandard filtering/firewall device on your home network that would be proxying your traffic?  One would think that it would proxy it for the other GeoIP services as well, though.  This is leaning towards some sort of problem in their database, in which case Zvi Twersky's answer may be more useful.